# How to limit date selection on UIDatePicker

Tags: swift, date, time, uidatepicker

I created a `UIDatePicker` and set the minimum selectable date. However I would like to know how can I limit selection so that user only may be able to select minutes by 5 minute intervals.

And as a result user can only select for example: 12:00, 12:05, 12:10, 12:15, 12:20, 12:25, 12:30 ... 12:55

This is my code so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
   datePicker.minimumDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 7200) // 7200 is equal to 2 hours
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your picker with a `minuteInterval`

```swift
datePicker.minuteInterval = 5
```

will make the picker increment in 5 minute intervals.

You can set the minute interval to whatever interval you need, but the number must evenly divide into 60

Comment: I didn't know about this property, thank you.